# How can I generate a brief (100) stream of random numbers, not using the computer or throwing dice?

Tags: random-number-generator

I am looking for a method of making random numbers that is off-line and is also independent of specialist equipment like a Geiger counter.

Comment: a deck of cards $\;$

Comment: Dice are specialist equipment?

Comment: Flip a coin? Cards makes the most sense - although make sure to shuffle them sufficiently many times using a riffle shuffle (other shuffles are either equivalent or worse) to ensure propper randomisation

Comment: What kind of number? 0/1? 1..6? π?

Comment: Do you expect cryptographically secure randomness, or merely some pseudo-random numbers? Do you assume the human brain to be “specialist equipment” or not? How will you solve the issue that an averagely trained human brain can not remember a sequence of 100 random numbers? Fun aside – your question is a mixture between **“not a real question”** and **“too broad”**. (I’m not sure if we even handle “lack-of-creativity” at Crypto.SE.) In the end, I decided to flag your question for being **too broad**.

Comment: Well that's really nice of you!

Answer (score 1):

Do a long jump, measure the distance in millimeters, take it modulo 10.

Repeat 100 times.

Another idea: use clock timer that shows milliseconds, start it and then turn off after some time, look at the last digit.

Comment: Too easy to measure incorrectly - people are bad measurers, they tend to cheat, round off, etc. Besides, we are cryptographers - have you ever seen one of us jump? Removed downvote, probably a joke :)

Comment: Why to cheat here? And it is not hard to measure with enough precision.

Comment: You may not intentionally cheat, but just be compelled to round off to e.g. half centimeters. If you do a lot of measuring, you will notice that this is quite a strong tendency. Besides that, a long jump requires a lot of equipment to be in place, and 100 jumps are not healthy. Gosh, you were not joking.

Comment: @owlstead Well, OP did not specify a time limit, so he could do, say, five jumps a day and be done in under two weeks. But yes, this kind of sampling is really not guaranteed to produce a uniform distribution.